# Pausing Javascript Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to pause this timer? And if it's paused how to unpause and continue counting? It should be a function

```js
function timer($time) {
    let $lorem = $("#lorem");
    function countdown() {
      let $minutes = Math.floor($time / 60);
      let $seconds = $time % 60;
      let $result = $minutes + ":" + ($seconds < 10 ? "0" + $seconds : $seconds);
      --$time;
      $lorem.text($result);
    }
    countdown();
    setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  }
  timer(200);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lorem"></div>
```

Comment: does my answer solved your problem? If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by storing the result of `setInterval` in a variable:

```
var timeKeeper = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

Then when you want to pause, use `clearInterval`:

```
clearInterval(timeKeeper);
```

This will stop the interval from executing. To start again, reset the timer variable:

```
timeKeeper= setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag `pause` with a click event, on click toogle pause:

```
  let pause = false;
  $lorem.on('click', function() {
    pause = !pause;
  });
```

Then check if `!pause` and time > 0 then reduce the time by 0.1s

If the time <= 0 to remove the interval just call `clearInterval(setInt)` (note you need to define it first like `let setInt = setInterval(countdown, 100);`)

Using 100ms because better precision when you pause, otherwise after a click, your clock still gonna run into next sec then stop.

If `!pause` then `$time = $time - 0.1;` continue. Otherwise keep the same time and pass to next call.

```js
function timer($time) {
  let $lorem = $("#lorem");
  let pause = false;
  let setInt = setInterval(countdown, 100);
  $('#pause').on('click', function() {
    pause = !pause;
  });

  function countdown() {
    if (!pause && $time > 0) {
      $time = ($time - 0.1).toFixed(1);
    }
    if($time <= 0){
      clearInterval(setInt);
    }

    let $minutes = Math.floor($time / 60);
    let $seconds = Math.ceil($time % 60);
    let $result = $minutes + ":" + ($seconds < 10 ? "0" + $seconds : $seconds);

    $lorem.text($result);
    console.log($time);
  }

}
timer(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lorem"></div>

<br>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
```

Comment: `setInterval()` is better than using `setTimeout()`.  With `setTimeout` the time to schedule and execute the callback function will not be accounted for in the time before the next timeout. So you will get a slight drift over time for each update.  With `setInterval()` there should be no drift.

Comment: @RJM do you have a reference, I did not know that, hmm, I will try a setInterval version

Comment: @RJM updated, using `setInterval()` I think you are right because the drift is not counted so yeah, thank!

Comment: Here's a fiddle that demonstrates it.  `setInterval()` does not drift but `setTimeout` does.  The `setInterval` will sometimes be off for one cycle if the function execution scheduling doesn't happen immediately, but the interval continues to fire right on schedule after that, whereas with `setTimeout()` any timing error continues to accumulate over time.   https://jsfiddle.net/h4h9sfep/

Comment: @RJM I see, the process time between the timeout are not counted, good to know!